# Why is the Response set in ExceptionFilter ignored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, exception, action-filter

I have the following exception filter:

```
public class ArgumentExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var exception = actionExecutedContext.Exception as ArgumentException;

        if (exception != null)
            actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
            {
                FailureReason = exception.Message
            });

        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

I then call the following action with a  null 'id':

```
    public object Get(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));

        return Client.getProfileForUser(ExternalAuthToken, id);
    }
```

I set a break point in the ExceptionFilter and while stepping through the code I can confirm it does set the Response correctly.

My logging action filter shows the response has been set correctly but the browser receives a Server 500 error with full exception details in HTML format.

I've tried:

- Setting customErrors to 'Off' and this had no effect.
- I've added Message Handler and checked that the response is correct at the Message Handler level. It is correct at this level.

Why is the response set in the filter being overridden, and by where in the pipeline would this be happening?

### Edit (Now Resolved)

I have resolved this issue by deleting the "bin" folder and rebuilding. I am not sure how this could have fixed it however.

Comment: I am also facing this problem, I believe it is caused by some changes in .net core 1.1 because I recently updated

Comment: Had the same problem and same solution. I was losing my mind trying to make it work so thank you! There's probably a caching problem causing this.